# Ubuntu persistent LiveUSB mac

Tags: live-usb

I made a bootable live usb drive with ubuntu 11.10 with the help of penguintosh, which uses an efi bootloader that loads the iso of the operating system. Is there anyway to make this installation persistent? Or is there another way that I can install ubuntu live usb for mac without refit (I want to be able to use it on numerous computers) that can make it persistent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably bug #1159016.  In short the persistence is created only on the syslinux boot, not on the grub boot, so you have to edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg and add the word "persistent" onto the linux boot line yourself.